# Request chatbot - 'NoneType' for 'split'

Tags: python, chatbot

I checked all the code and even tried to read other answers of this same error here on the forum, but I don't know where I'm wrong. Why AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'?

```
import re
from asyncio import (gather, get_event_loop, sleep)

from aiohttp import ClientSession
from pyrogram import (Client, filters, idle)
from Python_ARQ import ARQ

from config import bot, BOT_TOKEN, ARQ_API_KEY, ARQ_API_BASE_URL, LANGUAGE
bot_token= BOT_TOKEN

print("[INFO]: Checking... Your Details")

bot_id = int(bot_token.split(":")[0])
print("[INFO]: Code running by Jinn")
arq = None


async def lunaQuery(query: str, user_id: int):
    query = (
        query
        if LANGUAGE == "en"
        else (await arq.translate(query, "en")).result.translatedText
    )
    resp = (await arq.luna(query, user_id)).result
    return (
        resp
        if LANGUAGE == "en"
        else (
            await arq.translate(resp, LANGUAGE)
        ).result.translatedText
    )


    async def type_and_send(message):
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        user_id = message.from_user.id if message.from_user else 0
        query = message.text.strip()
        await message._client.send_chat_action(chat_id, "typing")
        response, _ = await gather(lunaQuery(query, user_id), sleep(2))
        if "Luna" in response:
            responsee = response.replace("Luna", "Nazriya")
        else:
            responsee = response
        if "Aco" in responsee:
            responsess = responsee.replace("Aco", "Nazriya")
        else:
            responsess = responsee
        if "Who is Nazriya?" in responsess:
            responsess2 = responsess.replace("Who is Nazriya?", "JINNS sister")
        else:
            responsess2 = responsess
        await message.reply_text(responsess2)
        await message._client.send_chat_action(chat_id, "cancel")
    
    
   @bot.on_message(
        ~filters.private | ~filters.group
        & filters.text
        & ~filters.command("start")
        & ~filters.edited,
    group=69,
)
```

I tried to change the return by yield, and change the attributes of the keys after the split.

In config I have this (don't know if it might be a problem here):

```
`from heroku3 import from_key
from pyrogram import Client

API_ID = int(os.environ.get("my id_telegram", "6"))
API_HASH = os.environ.get("my key",)
BOT_TOKEN = os.environ.get("my key", None)
ARQ_API_KEY = "my key" 
LANGUAGE = "en"
ARQ_API_BASE_URL = "https://thearq.tech"

bot = Client(":memory:",
             api_id=API_ID,
             api_hash=API_HASH,
             bot_token=BOT_TOKEN)`
```

I already tried to create a new file and do

```
from nazriya import bot_token

if bot_token is not None:
     print(bot_token)
else:
     pass
```

Comment: `BOT_TOKEN` in the `config` module must be null.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes i was with BOT_TOKEN = os.environ.get("Token", None)

Comment: Okay, so that explains it.  "Token" was not found in the environment.

Comment: @JohnGordon It was for example, I put my real token in config.py

Comment: Try printing `bot_token` and see what value you get.

Comment: @JohnGordon 'bot_token' is not defined

Comment: I don't see how that is possible.  The code in the question has `bot_token= BOT_TOKEN` as the very first line of code after the imports.  It has to be defined.

Comment: place `print(bot_token)` statements at various points in your program. What output does it give?

Comment: @Mous I did this in several points of it, and still with the same error

Comment: @JohnGordon I made an edit to show the config part

Comment: I had already read about this answer linked to my question on this forum, and it didn't help

Comment: I'm back now. What about straight after the assignment?